# I made nevigation drawer. How I can replace the layout with another on nevigation item selected?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity, android-studio

this is my xml. I put there text view (for the title) and list view.
I want to replace it with other fragment.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/stam"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/moreDetails"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/books"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and in the class I did this override function:

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "yeeeeeeee", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        final Fragment fragment = new SearchBookFragment();
        FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.stam, fragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }
```

The toast is shown but the view is not replaced.

Comment: is `LinearLayout` parent of xml and are you replacing inside activity?

Comment: Have you tried to change LinearLayout to FrameLayout or to change LinearLayout to fragment? Also is this LinearLayout root element of layout xml?